# UL element width not changing with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a `ul` acting as the navbar. I want it to open with the click of a button by changing its width, but it's not working. When the button is clicked nothing happens, however it should change the width and make the `ul` appear.

```js
function openNav() {
            document.getElementByClass("nav").style.width = "250px";
        }

        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementByClass("nav").style.width = "0px";
        }
```

```css
.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  position: fixed; /* Make it stick, even on scroll */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scrolling if the sidenav has too much content */
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openNav()">Open Nav</button>

    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="{% url 'sheets:list' %}" class="">Nav Element</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as `getElementByClass()`, you should use `getElementsByClassName()` instead, like in this code example:

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0].style.width = "250px";
 }

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0].style.width = "0px";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled the DOM element as `getElementByClass` it should be `getElementsByClassName` and the alternate thing would you can also make use of `querySelector` which is quite helpful sometimes.

Here is the code I have updated it for both the events.

```css
.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  position: fixed; /* Make it stick, even on scroll */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scrolling if the sidenav has too much content */
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script>
        function openNav() {
            document.querySelector(".nav").style.width = "250px";
        }

        function closeNav() {
            document.querySelector(".nav").style.width = "0px";
        }
    </script>
    <button onClick="openNav()">Open Nav</button>
    <button onClick="closeNav()">Close Nav</button>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="{% url 'sheets:list' %}" class="">Nav Element</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make so

```
     <button onclick="openNav()">Open Nav</button>

    <ul id='nav'>
        <li><a href="{% url 'sheets:list' %}" class="">Nav Element</a></li>
    </ul>

  </ul>

<button onclick="openNav()">Open Nav</button>

<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="{% url 'sheets:list' %}" class="">Nav Element</a></li>
</ul>
```

and width will change but you cant see it so change font-size